# colour particular items in a radio box using wxpython

Tags: python, radio-button, wxpython

Is it possible to colour text of specific item in a radio box? 
I am working with wxpython for building GUI and I have a list of file names with which I built a radio box. I now want to colour some file names with different colour.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. The wxPython toolkit wraps the native widget of the OS it is running in and I don't believe any OS allows that functionality out of the box for that widget. You would have to create a custom widget to do what you want. See the following wiki page for information on how to do that:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/CreatingCustomControls